# List folders and get the latest folder

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to get the folder with the latest datetime stamp?

My folders are like this:

```
>ls -la
20160904-1200
20160905-2200
20160907-2200
```

The format is:

```
YYYYMMDD-HHMM (24 hour time)
```

I am currently using this to list folders:

```
Dir["archive/#{current_archive_folder}/*.xml"]
```

But was hoping there was a builtin way to somehow grab the folder that has the most recent datetime.

Answer (score 0):

List the directories the same way you're listing your XML files, and sort them!

```
current_archive_folder = Dir["archive/*"].sort!
Dir["#{current_archive_folder}/*.xml"]
```